# IE9 not rendering site - but only in a certain environment

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, rendering

OK, this is perhaps the most bizarre situation I've seen in my programming career...

I'm working on a particular e-commerce site...it renders PERFECTLY in all browsers, including IE 8 through 11, Firefox (Windows, Linux, and OSX), Chrome (Windows, Linux, and OSX), and the Android browsers.

EXCEPT...in our QA environment, the site doesn't render in IE9. Problem: it's not loading jQuery. Again, JUST our QA environment. Other environments render it fine in IE9.

I don't understand what's going wrong. The jQuery source file is in the same directory as all the other JS files being used, and the functions in those files are working fine. And there's no minification being done, so that's not the issue either.

But just to reiterate: all browsers work fine in all environments, except for specifically IE9 specifically in our QA environment.

What should I be looking out for?

UPDATE:

I'm now noticing that in the QA environment, this code is not loading, but it is on other environments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE7]>
<html lang="en" class="ie7 oldie"></html><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>
<html lang="en" class="ie8 oldie"></html><![endif]-->
<!-- [if gt IE 8] <!-->
<html lang="en">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

I think that's the troublesome area. That code actually appears when "view source" on all working browsers, but in the nonworking situation -- again, IE9 in our QA environment -- that snip of code is NOT there; it's there in every other situation.

It appears that the conditional comments are just plain stripped out in our QA environment, and that's when the rendering gets all higgledy-piggledy.

Comment: What error do you get in console/network tab?

Comment: OK, I've figured out that for some reason IE9 is going into "quirks" mode on our QA environment. At least that's something for me to start from.